# Xamarin forms with Visual Studio 2017 throwing Unhandled Exception while testing on Android Emulator

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I'm developing an application in Xamarin Forms with Visual Studio 2017. I am easily able to GET and POST Data. But on PUT and DELETE functions, my code abruptly breaks with an unhandled exception that is not being detected in try/catch. Why is the exception being thrown, what is it and what am I doing wrong? I have been currently testing my app on Android Emulator. My code is as below.

```
    public async Task<bool> PutAsync(string id, ItemDetailsClass t)
    {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(t);

            HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(json);

            httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new 
            MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

            var result = await httpClient.PutAsync(WebServiceUrl + id, 
            httpContent);

            return result.IsSuccessStatusCode;

    }
```

My code runs into an exception in the second last line: `(var result = await httpclient.PutAsync(WebServiceUrl + id,httpContent);)`

But, I am able to get through smoothly for the PostAsync Method (which is as below):

```
    public async Task<bool> PostAsync(ItemDetailsClass t)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(t);

        HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(json);

        httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new 
        MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

        var result = await httpClient.PostAsync(WebServiceUrl, httpContent);

        return result.IsSuccessStatusCode;
    }
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does the REST service you are communicating with have PUT and DELETE endpoints? Have you tested them using something like Postman to check they are working correctly?

Comment: As an aside, I recommend using Refit for communication with a REST endpoint https://github.com/paulcbetts/refit Makes life a lot easier

Comment: @SteveChadbourne - I tested my Put endpoint using Postman and it gave me this error in "Pretty" - Unexpected '<' .


Any Idea what that means?

Comment: @SteveChadbourne - a part of the error shown in "Raw" is this: 

- The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used.